# Can you call a C function that takes function pointers as arguments?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

I want to use MathLink to call a function I wrote in C. However, similar to an integrator, it takes a function pointer as an argument and applies it on numbers depending on the other arguments.  I know how to pass lists of reals and so on, but can you also pass pointers to functions defined in Mathematica? In the end, it should look something like this:

```
f[x_,y_] := x*y; Install["mycprogram"]; MyCFunction[f,1,2]
```

`f` is a function that takes two doubles and returns a double. It's fairly simple and should always be some combination of polynomials, fractions, `Log` and `Exp`.

Comment: You can always write a simple wrapper functions in C that don't take pointers and just calls the function that does take pointers.

Comment: "Functions" in *Mathematica* are really rewrite rules and have no corresponding function pointer. You can get the function pointers to internal kernel functions that are written in C, but that's it.

Comment: Could you please make clear, how such functions `f` will look in your real world application? Is `f` a very complicated function which uses other non-trivial Mathematica functions (e.g. [special functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialFunctions.html) ). Or will `f` be build from basic operations like multiplication, addition and maybe some trigonometric functions? In the first case your `f` should probably be calculated by the kernel, in the latter it's maybe possible to compile it down to a C function.

Comment: @halirutan: I edited the post. It should always be computable by C.

Comment: Alternately, you could use Delegates and .NETLink to pass a mathematica function to a C function that uses a function pointer

Comment: MathLink does support callbacks to Mathematica.  Take a look at the `MLEvaluate()` and `MLEvaluateString()` functions.  You can build what you need using these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are several approaches to achieve the behavior you want but first let me point out that it is not possible to get a function pointer of a normal Mathematica function. A function pointer would require that the function was compiled but when you define a function inside Mathematica with e.g.

```
f[x_,y_] := x+y;
```

this is not the case as Oleksandr already pointed out.

Therefore, let me first give a solution which emulates the behavior you try to achieve. If you have a MathLink program or a [library function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/Overview.html)  which can be used inside Mathematica you can always evaluate any kind of expressions through MathLink-communication.

The idea now is to give your C-function the name of the Mathematica function (`f`) you want to call together with the numeric input. The you call inside your C-function the MathKernel and evaluate the call `f[x,y]` and use the result in the further computation.

Assume the following short library function (it is very similar to what you have to use in your MathLink program)

```c
#include "mathlink.h"
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return 0;
}

DLLEXPORT int func(WolframLibraryData libData, mint argc, MArgument *args, MArgument res)
{
    int pkt;
    mreal parm1, parm2, calc_result;
    char *f;

    f = MArgument_getUTF8String(args[0]);
    parm1 = MArgument_getReal(args[1]);
    parm2 = MArgument_getReal(args[2]);

    MLINK mlp = libData->getMathLink(libData);
    MLPutFunction(mlp, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
    MLPutFunction(mlp, f, 2);
    MLPutReal(mlp, parm1);
    MLPutReal(mlp, parm2);
    libData->processMathLink(mlp);
    pkt = MLNextPacket(mlp);
    if (pkt == RETURNPKT) MLGetReal(mlp, &calc_result);
    libData->UTF8String_disown(f);
    MArgument_setReal(res, calc_result);        
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

}
```

Assuming you have stored this inside the file "myfunc.c" then you can create the ready-to-use library with

```
<< CCompilerDriver`
CreateLibrary[{"myfunc.c"}, "myfunc", "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print]
```

The library is automatically put to a location where it can be found by Mathematica. When you have a closer look at the `func` function, you see that it expects a string and two double arguments. Then it simply uses a MathLink to evaluate the function-call `f[parm1,parm2]` and takes the result and just passes it back.

You can load and use this function inside your current session with

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y;
fun = LibraryFunctionLoad["myfunc", "func", {"UTF8String", _Real, _Real}, _Real]
fun["f", 1., 4.]

(*
    Out[4]= 5.
*)
```

Comment: Good, clear answer! Just to note that if `f` is itself a `LibraryFunction` then one should be able to use `LibraryFunctionPointer lfp = libData->compileLibraryFunctions->getFunctionCallPointer("f")` to get its function pointer. But I haven't tried this myself, so I'm not posting an answer including this for the time being.

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR., I had something similar in mind but didn't mention it since I was not sure whether the OP has to stick with a MathLink program. I thought about compiling the function `f` and then load the dll and call it manually. But even there you need the `libData` pointer which you usually don't have in a normal MathLink program. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Yes, I agree. If we're restricted to *MathLink*, I think you've already presented the best solution. The advantage of using `LibraryFunction`s, of course, is the lower call overhead due to not having to serialize everything. From my own tests, *MathLink* has a fairly high protocol overhead too. For a simple function like `f`, that'll probably be significant.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yep, thats why the answer took me so long: The OP stated that the function consists only of basic operations which would make it perfect for `Compile` and a call through the Library Link. The MathLink callback is in this case only a suboptimal solution.

Comment: But if we define the function `f` as `f := {x, y} |-> x + y` (or `f := #1 + #2 &`), it will no longer be a rewrite rule. Doesn't it have a corresponding function pointer?